# Why am I getting a 'Prepare for launch task failed unexpectedly' error when running my Docker Compose with ASP.NET Core microservices?

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose, microservices

Prepare for launch task failed unexpectedly (Docker Compose)

I created an image with details in docker-compose.yml and docker-compose.overide.yml

```yaml
version: '3.4'

services:
   catalog-api:
    image: ${REGISTRY:-Reddington}/catalog.api-${PLATFORM:-linux}-${TAG:-latest}
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Services/Catalog/Catalog.API/Dockerfile
```

---

```yaml
version: '3.4'

services:
  catalog-api:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - PATH_BASE=/catalog-api
    ports:
      - "5101:80"
      - "9101:81"
```

---

But when I run docker compose I received

> "Prepare for launch task failed unexpectedly"

error.

Comment: See following : https://docs.docker.com/desktop/troubleshoot/topics/